# Support vector machine - SVM - calculation on paper

Tags: machine-learning

I have a problem with SVM. I tried to solve this but it doesn't work. I followed a guide on this [link](https://asmquantmacro.com/2016/06/14/support-vector-machines-without-tears-part-1/), but I'm lost.
Okay, the problem:

I have dataset $D = {((0,0),-1),((2,4),-1),((4,2),-1),((6,4),+1),((6,8),+1),((8,8),+1)}$

I need to find a hard margin (A), write a linear model $h(x)$ that corresponds to that margin (B), and determine the width of the margin (C), as well as the offset (D). I also have to determine the support vectors (E).
Finally, I need to find the class in which the instance $(5,6)$ should be found (F).

I need to calculate all this (A-F) using a calculator only, not using some algorithm for the computer. Honestly, I can't find any material to guide me on how to solve this on paper, I only can find computer algorithms.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: The idea is you need to either get points $A$ and $B$ so that the perpendicular to $AB$ through A splits the sets and same with B. If that’s not possible, you need A, $B_1$,$B_2$ so that the parallel to $B_1B_2$ through A splits the sets and $B_1B_2$ cuts off the rest of the $B$ points. Try (4,2) and (6,4).